# How to create a function in Reactjs that is not called by an event Listener?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner in reactjs and am trying to create a simple quiz app. What I want to do can be seen in the selectionQues() function.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Question from './components/Question';


function App() {

  const [ques, setques] = useState([]);
  const [currentQues, setcurrentQues] = useState([]);

  //importing ques using api
  useEffect(() =>{
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20&category=18&difficulty=medium&type=multiple')
    .then((res)=> res.json())
    .then((question) => {
      setques(question.results);
    });

  },[setques])


  //selecting 5 ques at random for our quiz

  const selectingQues = () => {
    let curr=[];
    let qlen=ques.length;
    for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
      let selector= Math.floor(Math.random()*qlen);
      curr[i]=ques[selector];
    }
    setcurrentQues(curr);
    // console.log(ques);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Question currentQues={currentQues}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now what I want to do is call this SelectingQues() without explicitly using a onClick listener or anything of the like. Is this possible using useEffect? But i want it to be executed after the first useEffect has been called.

Question component is not attached since rn it does nothing more than just displaying the ques.

Comment: why do you want to call selectingQues? Do you want to render quiz questions? please what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @Marium: AsalamuALykum ! What do you precisely mean by call "question"? Could you please elaborate. In useEffect() I believe  we can achieve what you seek, But Clarify what you want to achieve ? Thanks

Comment: `But i want it to be executed after the first useEffect has been called` -- you can call it inside the `useEffect` callback, and store some state so that you can't call it again

Comment: @AbuSufian Hi! so what i want to do is display 5 ques at a time so i randomly select those ques since the API contains 20 question. so i have created a new state that stores those 5 questions.

Comment: so if i understand correctly you want to call it after api request is successfull

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Walaikumsalam. My bad i typed it wrong it was call the function selectingQuestion(). Ive edited it now

Comment: you can add another `useEffect` which can check for `curr` state update if it is divisible by 5 then you can call `selectingQues`

Comment: Is this possibly a scenario where your job would be simplified by stopping trying to use a functional component with all these `useState` and `useEffect` things, and instead just using a stateful component? I feel like people sometimes put a lot of unecessary effort into keeping components functional when there's not necessarily a good reason to

Comment: @TKoL I think i will try one of ur solutions. thank you

Comment: @MariumAli: Have come up with the solution for your problem. It's straight forward. If you have any questions let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IDEA:** Main Idea is to get our Questions array in our API call and make sure to get random 5 questions there itself. How I do this is, as soon as I am receiving my data from my API call, I do a `promise chaining` and handle all my code for get 5 random questions in this another `then()` block. As I receive my 5 random questions, I saved in the state `currentQues`.

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/questionanswerquizapp-nq88l)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [currentQues, setcurrentQues] = useState([]);

  //importing ques using api
  useEffect(() => {
    selectingQues();
  }, []);

  // selecting 5 ques at random for our quiz

  const selectingQues = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20&category=18&difficulty=medium&type=multiple"
    );

    const data = await response.json();

    console.log(data);
    const initialQuestions = data.results;
    let curr = [];
    // console.log(initialQuestions.length);
    let length = initialQuestions.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let selector = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
      curr[i] = initialQuestions[selector];
    }
    setcurrentQues(curr);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {currentQues.length > 0 && <Question currentQuestions={currentQues} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const Question = ({ currentQuestions }) => {
  // const { question, correct_answer } = question;
  console.log(currentQuestions);
  return (
    <>
      {currentQuestions.map((question) => (
        <div key={question.question}>
          <p>
            <strong>Question:</strong> {question.question}
          </p>

          <p>
            <strong>Answer:</strong> {question["correct_answer"]}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: @MariumAli: This is the working code for you. Do vote and accept the answer if this answer is useful to you. This will help other questioners as well. Thank You :)

Comment: Thank you so much! So basically my idea was ok but my execution was wrong :). You've been a great help thnx!!

Comment: AnyTime :) You are most welcome :) Yup  your Idea was right to get the data first and get 5 random questions from there itself. Keep it up !!!